# Find Starting Number in Sigma Notation Problem

Tags: calculus, summation

Suppose that $\sum_{k=a}^{106} (2k-3) = 10,001$ . What is the value of a? 
You are not allowed to use trial and error, use algebra instead.

I know that $a=34$ because of an online calculator and trial and error. How would I be able to find the answer algebraically? Thank you.

$$\sum_{k=a}^{106} (2k-3) = 10,001$$

Comment: Hint: sums are linear, i.e., $\sum_{k=a}^b u_k + u_k = \sum_{k=a}^b u_k + \sum_{k=a}^b v_k$.

Comment: Do you know the formula for $\sum_{k=0}^n k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setup:**

$\sum\limits_{k=a}^{106}(2k-3)=2(\sum\limits_{k=a}^{106}k)+(-3)(\sum\limits_{k=a}^{106}1)$

Now... the following two summation formulae are useful to know:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n 1 = n$$

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

With these in mind, we can come up with more general formulae for if the index begins at a different number instead of at $1$ by remembering $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(k) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{a-1}f(k) + \sum\limits_{k=a}^nf(k)$, that is to say we can split up the summation into multiple parts.

Now, we should have a way to express the original expression without the summation symbols as a polynomial in terms of $a$.  We are told that the original expression should be equal to $10001$, so all that remains is to solve for the value of $a$.

---

**Further details:**

> For $a\leq n$ we have $\sum\limits_{k=a}^n 1 = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n 1 - \sum\limits_{k=1}^{a-1}1 = n - (a-1) = n-a+1$.  Similarly we have $\sum\limits_{k=a}^n k = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k - \sum\limits_{k=1}^{a-1} k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{(a-1)a}{2}$

Now... for your specific problem this means:

> $\sum\limits_{k=a}^{106} (2k-3)=2(\frac{106(107)}{2}-\frac{(a-1)a}{2}) - 3(106-a+1)=-a^2+4a+11021$

Which, remember we wanted to be equal to $10001$, giving us the equation to solve:

> $-a^2+4a+11021=10001$.  Now, we subtract $10001$ from each side...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am still lost. How can we solve for a? There are still too many variables.

Comment: @cukboi "*There are still too many variables*".  There is only one variable.  First, calculate the sum as though it started at $1$ instead.  This should have nothing to do with $a$ and should be straightforward to calculate given the two formulae I listed.  Next...calculate the sum as though it started at $1$ and ended at $a-1$.  This should again be straightforward to calculate but this time will have something to do with $a$.  Now, subtracting the one result from the other will give you a way of expressing the sum that started at $a$ and ended at $106$ in terms of $a$.

Comment: Ok. I wound up with $a^2 - 4a - 11021$ and got a = -103 and 107. Neither of these are 34. What did I do wrong.

Comment: @cukboi what you did wrong is that you set that equal to zero and solved for $a$.  What you should have done is set that equal to what we wanted it equal to as per the problem statement... namely $10001$

Comment: Ahh ok. Now I see. I got a = -30 and 34, I dropped the -30 because it is out of the domain, and I plugged in 34 and got 10001. Thank you!